# Best way to secure a mule 4 application

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

I am using Mule 4 and Anypoint 7.  I am looking at how I can secure my mule application so it can only be access by teams within my company.  The API would be sending customer groupings and stats and may start to include personal identifiable information at a later date.

I have setup client id and client secret in the RAML and enforcing it in API manager.

I'm new to security and just wanted an opinion on if I should be considering to use OAuth2, SAML or LDAP and if so which one would be the best?  We already have Okta and AD being used within the company and not sure if we can leverage these also.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you the schema that I currently have for my application.

On cloudhub I've deployed my application which listen port 8091.
I've then create a proxy application (managed by API manager) secured with ip filter and Basic Auth which call (thanks to VPC) the application as "mule-worker-internal-appname".